# How getInstallerPackageName() in android JNI

Tags: java, android, java-native-interface

I'm trying to use the method 
`context.getPackageManager().getInstallerPackageName(context.getPackageName());`

in android JNI interface. This is what I've already do, but I don't know how continue:

```
//   context
jclass native_context = env->GetObjectClass(thiz);

// context.getPackageManager()
jmethodID methodID_func = env->GetMethodID(native_context, "getPackageManager", "()Landroid/content/pm/PackageManager;");
jobject package_manager  = env->CallObjectMethod(thiz,methodID_func);
jclass pm_clazz = env->GetObjectClass(package_manager);

//packageManager.getInstallerPackageName()
jmethodID methodId_pm = env->GetMethodID(pm_clazz,"getInstallerPackageName","(Ljava/lang/String)Landroid/content/pm/getInstallerPackageName;");

//context.getPackageName()
jmethodID methodID_packagename = env->GetMethodID(native_context,"getPackageName","()Ljava/lang/String;");
jstring name_str = static_cast<jstring>(env->CallObjectMethod(thiz,methodID_packagename));

jstring intaller = static_cast<jstring>(env->CallObjectMethod(package_manager,methodId_pm,name_str));
LOGD("%s", getCharFromString(env, intaller));`
```

Logcat error:
`06-04 18:18:41.445: A/art(28904): art/runtime/java_vm_ext.cc:410] JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: JNI GetMethodID called with pending exception java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: no non-static method "Landroid/app/ApplicationPackageManager;.getInstallerPackageName(Ljava/lang/String)Landroid/content/pm/PackageManager/getInstallerPackageName;"`

My goal is to get the installer package name in JNI interface and check piracy apps (Java is too weak).

Thank You.

Comment: Why `Ljava/lang/String;I` ? As far as I can tell, `getInstallerPackageName` only takes one argument (a `String`).

Comment: Sorry, my bad. But it still does not works, and the error on logcat is the same

Comment: Well, `Landroid/content/pm/getInstallerPackageName;` is hardly the correct return type.

Comment: were you able to complete this ?

Answer (score 0):

getInstallerPackageName() gets a String and returns a string, so the line should be:

```
jmethodID methodId_pm = env->GetMethodID(pm_clazz,"getInstallerPackageName","(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;");
```